# Index keeps getting reset inside return for map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map that I am using to iterate over. I have the value index which is counting 0,1,2,3,4, etc. Unfortunately it seems to have a different value in the inner-nested return statement. Do I need to pass this value to the inner return statement? I left 3 comments in the code. Any idea how to keep `index` as 0,1,2,3,4,5?

```js
Object.keys(element.auditdiff).map((dataType, index) => {
  console.log(index); // is giving me 0, 1,2,3,4,5
  if (dataType !== "Lid" && dataType !== "Datacenter" && dataType !== "Id")
    return Object.keys(element.auditdiff[dataType]).map((data, job) => {
      console.log(index); //is only giving me 2,3
      return (
        <Table.Row key={data}>
          <Table.Cell>
            <Button
              content="Update Row"
              color="green"
              disabled={updated.indexOf(index) > -1}
              onClick={() => {
                this.handleUpdate(index);  // should send 1,2,3,4,5
              }}
            />
          </Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      );
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, you have that `if` statement there which filters out some of the data types and thus indexes.

Comment: `.map` should return the same length of the array. You might want to filter first `arr.filter(...).map(...)`

Comment: Anyway, you should probably refactor your code so you don't rely on opaque integer indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the below code, your map function is not getting executed for all values in the array and that is why you see 2 and 3
`if (dataType !== "Lid" && dataType !== "Datacenter" && dataType !=="Id")`

Do you want the index to the top map function? If you want index from `Object.keys(element.auditdiff[dataType]).map((data, job) => {`

You might want to use the index from `job` map function and see if that works

Comment: job is not what I want since that is only 0 or 1 because it is a map. How would I grab the index to the top map function?

Comment: you are already doing that by call `index`. But because of your if statement, some of the values in `auditdiff` are not passing `dataType !== "Lid" && dataType !== "Datacenter" && dataType !== "Id"` check

Comment: only elements in index 2 and 3 are passing, hence you see index as 2 and 3

Comment: Is there any way I can keep the if statement but keep the index?

Comment: Why do you need access to that index? Why cant you make another variable and use that as the counter starting from 0.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I do that though @Mukund?